# how to restrict users switching from su command

Tags: switch-statement, command, su, restrict, rhel8

How can I restrict users switching by su command..? suppose there are 3 users (root,user1 and user2)
only root and user1 can switch by using su command. root or user1 should not be able to switch to user 2 by using su command.

```
root su - user1 ----- ok
sudo su - (from user1 )--------- ok
root su - user2 ------ should be blocked
sudo su - user 2 (frm user 1) ------------ should be blocked
```

How can I do this

OS is RHEL 7

Comment: check here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64860